# VLC media player (PC) select audio track for conversion

Tags: vlc-media-player

When using *VLC media player for Win*, to convert a video with multiple audio tracks into another format, outputing using only one audio track, how do I select the audio track that is converted? VLC defaults to the first audio track.

Specifically:

```
Input  => MKV: Video + Audio (1=English / 2=French / 3=Spanish / 4=German)
Output => MP4: Video + Audio (Spanish)
```

Please, no workarounds.
In fact, right now I use MKVToolNix to remove the undesired audio track(s) and then convert the file in VLC. However, I wonder what the solution within VLC is - or whether one exists.

I checked this question, but it was specifically for Linux:
[VLC media player select audio track for conversion](https://superuser.com/questions/1026370/vlc-media-player-select-audio-track-for-conversion/1635010)

Thanks

Comment: The answers to the linked question *seem* OS-agnostic (although not perfectly clear in guidance). Is there no `Show more options` checkbox in the Windows version of the player? Is there no `Edit Options` field? Or maybe you tried `:audio-track=…` but it didn't work. Why exactly do you think the answers are "specifically for Linux"? Note: I don't use Windows, so I cannot verify if VLC misses some options there. If you tell me it does then I won't argue. What version of VLC are you using?

Comment: Seems i was expecting these features be available on GUI's, which is not. They do exist in command line.

Comment: This is the image:

![Win VLC GUI](https://imgur.com/a/36JDFil)

Comment: The `Show more options` checkbox should be available in the `Open media` window which precedes windows shown in your image.

Comment: no, no... there's no "show more options" in windows "open"